# Spring JNDI-lookup ternary operator

Tags: java, spring, jndi

I have XML configuration in my web-app. I have following tag in this file:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="my.super.queue" resource-ref="true" 
     jndi-name="#{ ${my.flag} ? ${jms.my.queue1} : ${jms.my.queue2} }"/>
```

The idea is to initiate queue based on a flag in properties. But, it seems that `jee:jndi` does not support ternary operator. I have the following error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'my.super.queue': Initialization of bean failed
Property or field 'jms' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?
<jee:jndi-lookup id="my.super.queue" resource-ref="true" jndi-name="#{ ${my.flag} ? ${jms.my.queue1} : ${jms.my.queue2} }"/>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Why the complexity? If you can set the flag why not simply set the queue name instead?

Comment: @M.Deinum , yes, you are right. but is it possible to use ternary operator in this tag attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. Need just to add quotes `'` to the operator:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="my.super.queue" resource-ref="true" 
     jndi-name="#{ ${my.flag} ? '${jms.my.queue1}' : '${jms.my.queue2}' }"/>
```

That's all. Thanks @M. Denium for inspiration.